# index out of range in python dictionary

Tags: python

im trying to implement a dictionary where in key is a number <=10^9 and value is a list of numbers.

```
 a=[] 
 for i in xrange(n):
     h,j = raw_input().split() 
     b=int(h)
     l=int(j)

     a[b].append(l)
```

It gives me a list index out of range error.

Comment: `a` is an empty list, any index will be out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here:

```
In [15]: from collections import defaultdict

In [16]: dic=defaultdict(list)

In [17]: for _ in xrange(4):
   ....:     h,j=map(int,raw_input().split())
   ....:     dic[h].append(j)
   ....:     
1 10
1 20
2 30
3 5

In [18]: dic
Out[18]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [10, 20], 2: [30], 3: [5]})
```

or use a simple dict and use `dict.setdefault`:

```
In [19]: dic={}  #use {} for declaring a new dict

In [20]: for _ in xrange(4):
   ....:     h,j=map(int,raw_input().split())
   ....:     dic.setdefault(h,[]).append(j)
   ....:     
1 10
1 20
2 30
3 5

In [21]: dic
Out[21]: {1: [10, 20], 2: [30], 3: [5]}
```

Sorting a dictionary:

Dictionaries can't be sorted, but we can get a list of sorted `key,value` pairs or just `keys` or just `values` using `sorted`:

```
In [25]: dic={1: [10, 30], 2: [30], 3: [5,50]}

In [26]: sorted(dic.items(),key=lambda x:sum(x[1])) #sort based on sum of lists
Out[26]: [(2, [30]), (1, [10, 30]), (3, [5, 50])]
```

Now you can create an `orderedDict` from this previous list using `collections.OrderedDict`, as it preserves the order in which the keys were inserted:

```
In [27]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [30]: od=OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(),key=lambda x:sum(x[1])))

In [31]: od
Out[31]: OrderedDict([(2, [30]), (1, [10, 30]), (3, [5, 50])])
```

Comment: how do i traverse through this dictionary?for example if i wanted to sort it based on sum of elements in the list.